# formula evaluation in cells when import excel sheet in R using read_excel

Tags: r

I want to import some excel files to R using `read_excel`(measured values by an instrument, with some parameters calculated using other measured values, so it has lots of formulas in some of the cells), I want to import all the files once, but when I import the files, I find the cells with formula are 0, they are not evaluated.

the basic code are:

```
library(readxl)
readxl_6800 <- function(path, name_rows = 42, data_rows = 43){
  data_name <- read_excel(path, range= cell_rows(name_rows))
  df <- read_excel(path, skip = data_rows, col_names = FALSE)
  colnames(df) <- colnames((data_name))
  return (df) 
} 
df
```

the results are:

```
# A tibble: 360 x 10
obs        time elapsed date                 TIME     E     A    Ca    Ci   Pci
 <dbl>       <dbl>   <dbl> <chr>               <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     1 1500971222.       0 20170725 16:27~    1.50e9     0     0     0     0     0
3     3 1500971224.       2 20170725 16:27~    1.50e9     0     0     0     0     0
4     4 1500971224.       3 20170725 16:27~    1.50e9     0     0     0     0     0
5     5 1500971226.       4 20170725 16:27~    1.50e9     0     0     0     0     0
```

where the zero values should be values larger than zero.

the sample excel can be download from:

[example file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/6i1d9kclen659l1/leaf.xlsx?dl=0)

how can I import the excel in this form with the formula evaluated? any suggestions?

I do not want to rewrite these formulas in R, as it will add lots of codes in R, it is the last choice.

Comment: It's highly unlikely folks are going to create an account on a service to download a file. Also, Microsoft Excel generally stores the computed value of the cells along with the formula.  Find the equivalent of "Calculate Sheet" in your version of Excel and use it and then re-save the files. `read_excel()` picks up the calculated  values. The `xlsx` package seems to have an option to refresh formulas on ingestion but I've not used it for that so cannot confirm.

Comment: I am sorry for the links need to register, I have changed it to dropbox, and the reason I do not want to use excel to resave is that I want to write a batch program, and then people can import lots of files by the program once to save time, as the data files can be hundreds.

Comment: I just wonder why the formulas can not be evalute in such a excel files with this form, as I know the formluas in a file with rectangular data form can be evlauted without any problem

Answer (score 0):

I searched the same issue and google brings me here. Moreover, I happen to find we are actually dealing with the same type of excel file, which comes from the LICOR machine...
In case anyone meet the same issue, I found it might be related to the `Excel Options-Enable iterative calculation`. My solution is, open the file, select "enable iterative calculation", save the file, and excute `read_excel()` in R again, then I get the correct data.

Comment: Use appropriate tags in your question.

Comment: wow, after a long time i found the answer of the question, thanks. I tried to use `XLConnect` and a python library called `xlwings` to sove the prolem.  and i prepared a python gui program to convert all the excel to csv files in batch with the format of tidy data.  here is the python programs: [https://github.com/zhujiedong/LI6800_excel2csv](https://github.com/zhujiedong/LI6800_excel2csv). `XLConnect` is good but need JRE support.  the gui program is for someone who may need not to use JRE dependence.